# Editor Text Fabricjs - IText format letters and simultaneous selection textDecoration

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

https://jsfiddle.net/gislef/Lvfpq57h/

To make this editor I took as a basis the kitchensink text editor, I consulted the [fabric js documentation about IText](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.IText.html) and saw some isolated examples in Jsfiddle.

I have two questions:

- How do I select letters and format only that was selected within the text?
- How do I get to select the three options simultaneously the text decoration: underline, line-through and overline?

Current code:

```js
radios5 = document.getElementsByName("fonttype");  // wijzig naar button
for(var i = 0, max = radios5.length; i < max; i++) {
    radios5[i].onclick = function() {

        if(document.getElementById(this.id).checked == true) {
            if(this.id == "text-cmd-bold") {
                canvas.getActiveObject().set("fontWeight", "bold");
            }
            if(this.id == "text-cmd-italic") {
                canvas.getActiveObject().set("fontStyle", "italic");
            }
            if(this.id == "text-cmd-underline") {
                canvas.getActiveObject().set("textDecoration", "underline");
            }
            if(this.id == "text-cmd-linethrough") {
                canvas.getActiveObject().set("textDecoration", "line-through");
            }
            if(this.id == "text-cmd-overline") {
                canvas.getActiveObject().set("textDecoration", "overline");
            }

        } else {
            if(this.id == "text-cmd-bold") {
                canvas.getActiveObject().set("fontWeight", "");
            }
            if(this.id == "text-cmd-italic") {
                canvas.getActiveObject().set("fontStyle", "");
            }  
            if(this.id == "text-cmd-underline") {
                canvas.getActiveObject().set("textDecoration", "");
            }
            if(this.id == "text-cmd-linethrough") {
                canvas.getActiveObject().set("textDecoration", "");
            }  
            if(this.id == "text-cmd-overline") {
                canvas.getActiveObject().set("textDecoration", "");
            }
        }


        canvas.renderAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this code!! i'm stating with fabricjs and canvas and it looks great, have you any issues with this? looks like it working fine! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your an example you're using the version of `fabric.js` `1.5.0`

In the last (and probably before) version of `fabric.js` we have the method for changing styles for the only selected text. [Here](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Text.html#setSelectionStyles) in the doc is a description of this method

You can use it just like this:

```js
canvas.getActiveObject().setSelectionStyles({
  underline: true,
  overline: true
})
```